# ASP.Net control to select a file (not upload)

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I want to have a control which allows a user to click a link button, a file dialog comes up and the user selects a file. Currently I am using the [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control as such:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDocumentLocation" runat="server" CausesValidation="False">Please Select...</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuDocumentLocation" style="display:none;" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" />
```

And in the code behind I have in `Page_Load`:

```
btnDocumentLocation.OnClientClick = "$('[id*=\"" + fuDocumentLocation.ClientID + "\"]').click();";
```

This launches the (hidden) `FileUpload` control where you select your file. In `Page_Load` it checks the file as below and updates the `Text` of the `LinkButton`. I do not need the actual file contents, just the file location:

```
if (IsPostBack && fuDocumentLocation.PostedFile != null && fuDocumentLocation.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
{
    btnDocumentLocation.Text = fuDocumentLocation.PostedFile.FileName;
}
else
{
    btnDocumentLocation.Text = "";
}
```

This all works fine when ran locally. When published, the `FileUpload` seems to have an issue in the "uploading" part. It doesn't post back to the server and therefore can't run the `Page_Load` code to populate the `btnDocumentLocation.Text` property. I don't need it to grab the file, I just need the file location.

What I need to happen in order:

- User clicks on `LinkButton`
- File dialog box pops up
- User selects a file
- `LinkButton` `Text` property set to full file name selected

Is there a control that allows for this without the overhead of getting the file data in the request? And will allow you to select files across different shares?

Comment: use `jquery` for this simple displaying file name only

Comment: Have a look at my answer. Hope you will get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you post back the page if you only want to change the text ? Instead, you can achieve the same without postback using Jquery/Javascript as mentioned below:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnDocumentLocation" OnClientClick="return GetFile();" >Browse...</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuDocumentLocation" OnChange="ChangeText(this.value);" style="display: none" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeText(selectedPath) {
        $('#' + '<%=btnDocumentLocation.ClientID%>').text(selectedPath);
    }

    function GetFile() {
        $('#' + '<%=fuDocumentLocation.ClientID%>').click();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

**If you want to use Pure JQuery then:**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnDocumentLocation"  >Browse...</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuDocumentLocation"  style="display: none" />


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#' + '<%=btnDocumentLocation.ClientID%>').click(function () {
            $('#' + '<%=fuDocumentLocation.ClientID%>').click();
            return false;
        });

        $('#' + '<%=fuDocumentLocation.ClientID%>').change(function () {
            var selectedPath = $('#' + '<%=fuDocumentLocation.ClientID%>').val();
            $('#' + '<%=btnDocumentLocation.ClientID%>').text(selectedPath);

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is closest to what I am looking but when selecting the file, the `FileUpload` control still posts back to the server. This means that it is still sending the chosen file through as a request and if it is a large file it can take a while to post back. Which is kind of the issue I initially posted...In reverse...In that it works for users not on the local server, but if you try to access it from the local server you could be faced with a lengthy wait while the file "uploads". Is there a way to stop the propagation of the post back?

Comment: @anothershrubery: can you tell me when does it postback page ? because i dont think that on selecting file, your page will get post back

Comment: When I select a file from the `FileUpload` dialog, it changes the `LinkButton` text, via jQuery, then it posts back to the page.

Comment: @anothershrubery: make sure that you have written `return` before you call the `GetFile();` method. and in JavaScript method `return false` has been written. and also remove the code which you have written in page load event for the **btnDocumentLocation**'s **OnClientClick**

Comment: I had the `return false` in the wrong location! Thanks for that, working now!

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnDocumentLocation"  >Browse...</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuDocumentLocation"  style="display: none" />


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#' + '<%=btnDocumentLocation.ClientID%>').click(function () {
        $('#' + '<%=fuDocumentLocation.ClientID%>').click();
        return false;
    });

    $('#' + '<%=fuDocumentLocation.ClientID%>').change(function () {
        var selectedPath = $('#' + '<%=fuDocumentLocation.ClientID%>').val();
        $('#' + '<%=btnDocumentLocation.ClientID%>').text(selectedPath);

    });
});
```